# Spliting video with ffmpeg producing wrong durations

Tags: bash, audio, ffmpeg, video, encoding

I'm currently using a framework where I have to split a video (originally encoded with HEVC video and AAC audio) in multiple parts to process them separately. Then the final result is obtained by combining each of these pieces (currently done using the concat demuxer). To split, I use:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:03:00 -reset_timestamps 1 -f segment split/split_%02d.mkv
```

However, when inspecting the segments more closely, some present weird behaviour. For example, when playing some of them, the video progress bar will indicate that there are 3-4 seconds to go, but the video will suddenly end.

This only happens with a minority of the segments. Still, when combining them in the subsequent step, this results in the final video freezing for the 3-4 seconds before it resumes playing, which looks bad. How do I fix this (preferably without re-enconding)?

**Alternative things I've tried to no avail**

- Exchanging `-c copy` for `-c:v libx265` in the above command
- Using `-force_key_frames 'expr:gte(t,n_forced*20)'`
- Using a bash script with a for loop and multiple `-ss <initial_time> -t <duration>` commands and `-c copy`